# Access B"i" variable inside loop

Tags: java, android, loops

I am writing Java in Android Studio and I to access differend B variables in the loop. I am not quite sure about the syntax.

```
int A, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5;
for (i = 0; i++; i <= 20) {
    A=b"i";
}
```

Comment: The word you need to google is "array".

Comment: You cannot write this. You are looking for [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). I would recommend a [basic Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access variables like this.
You have to define a `List` or an `array`

```
int A = 0;
int[] myIntArray = {1,2,3,4,5};

for (int i = 0; i < myIntArray.length; i++){
    //Now you can access your array with the index
    A = myIntArray[i]; //This statement still does not make much sense
}
```

You should read some java beginner tutorials like [this one](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java.html)

Comment: thnx. Actually im trying to set into A the values of the strings paper_url_"i" ... so probably something like:
    A = paper_url_[i]

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to know what you mean, but I will make a guess.

```
int A, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5;

    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 1: A = B1;
                    break;
            case 2: A = B2;
                    break;
            case 3: A = B3;
                    break;
            case 4: A = B4;
                    break;
            case 5: A = B5;
                    break;
            default: break;
        }
        someFunction(A);
    }
```

I don't understand why you have `i <= 20` in your loop. Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

What i was trying to do :P

```
    String Url = "";
    int i;

    String [] paper_url;
    paper_url = new String[2];
    paper_url[0] = new String("http://www.google.com");
    paper_url[1] = new String("http://www.yahoo.com");

    for (i=1;i<=2;i++) {
        Url = paper_url[i];
    }
```